# Struggling to get started with electronic devices and circuits

Tags: education

A pass in electronic devices and circuits is mandatory in order to clear the first semester of my computer science engineering degree. The recommended text for studying is [Electronic Devices And Circuits By Millman.](http://books.google.co.in/books/about/Electronic_devices_and_circuits.html?id=RQEjAAAAMAAJ)

I'm unable to determine the prerequisite (which I really need to know) as the opening sentence of the preface reads "This book, intended as a text for a first course in electronics for electrical engineering or **physics** students."

The point is, this book doesn't look like an introductory text on electronics! The first chapter is titled "Electron Ballistics and Applications," and he starts off with the basic concepts of charged particles and then the Classical and Wave-mechanical models of the electron. Then he moves on to Force on charged particles in constant electric field.

Fortunately the things that I've mentioned above don't sound foreign to me, at least I'm in a position to say that they are all physics!

Here's my situation: I'm in a hopeless situation as I can't figure out how to get started. I've had an introductory physics course covering mechanics, electricity, magnetism, and optics 10-12 years ago and I never performed well. I struggled a lot, both in physics and mathematics.

The question is: How much physics and/or mathematics do I need to know in order to fully understand the text and do well in my examination? I'm willing to put in a lot of effort and I really need your advice.

Comment: I'am looking for a proper advice,not negative vote.Thanks Anyways!

Comment: Have you actually read the book, or have you read the first few pages & decided it's not electronics?

Comment: I have tried to ead the first few pages,but with no luck

Comment: Sounds like the book starts at the physics-end and works up, might be easier to start at a higher level and worry about the physics later. My college textbook was "Electronic systems" by MW Brimicombe, that treats things as black boxes (we don't care how they work, we just know what they do) and goes from there. I suck at maths but unfortunately you can't really avoid it in electronics, or physics, or computing, as so much is described by/in mathematical terms. It's an unfortunate fact of life in this universe.

Comment: So what is the actual class like?

Comment: Not quite sure why the down-votes, especially without a comment explaining the reason. @Alok you might have pissed-off people here (just guessing), showing disinterest in actually learning electronics, and focusing on passing alone ! Like any subject matter, the experience of learning depends a lot on your own interest, the instruction material (in terms of quality / style) and approach that your instructor (or you) take to learning it. For starters you might like to fix at least 2 things -- the book and attitude. Search for QnA on good book to start.

Comment: I never mentioned that my intention is just passing.If that's the case why would i say that i'am willing to learn whatever that's meant to be learnt to understand electronics?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you're from India and might be familiar to the CBSE board & NCERT.

You don't need a lot of physics to know semiconductor devices- basic stuff like current, voltage, Kirchhoff's laws. Get the book 'Engineering Circuit Analysis' by Hayt, Kemmerly and Durbin and solve examples and little extra problems till Chapter 11 and it will be more than enough to clear your concepts.

Then, read the chapter 'Semiconductor Devices' from Class XII NCERT Physics Textbook, Part II,  Chapter 14 (http://ncert.nic.in/NCERTS/textbook/textbook.htm?leph2=3-7">Link). The chapter has very little physics and will clear a lot of elementary concepts about semiconductor devices. Then you can read Electronic Devices and Circuit Theory from Boylestad and Nashelsky which is what I'm doing right now.

If you want, you can also watch http://www.nptel.iitm.ac.in/courses.php?disciplineId=117">ECE lectures from NPTEL (Indian Institute of Technology Lecture Videos). I found this lecture series somewhat helpful: http://www.nptel.iitm.ac.in/video.php?subjectId=117106087">Link.

Answer (score 0):

The mentioned book of millman is horrible. I suggest getting Electronic Devices by Thomas Floyd. It's very good for beginners and you will like it.